# Modify database for extended models

Tags: database, laravel, extend

I have this situation:

I have a table for `Person` (called `persons`). A person has a Name, an ID and a type (natural or juridical).
Then I have `Organization`, it of course is a juridical person that extends a `Person` and has specific fields like `manager_id` or `employees`.
Then I have an `Authority` which is a special government `Organization`, so in the end is also a `Person` and also has special required fields like `decree_number` (the number and year of the decree that constituted the `Authority`).

Then I have my database, where I have a table called `persons`.

My question is: should I create a new table for `organizations` and then another one for `authorities`? If not, how should I store the new fields that are required for Authorities or Organizations but not for a Persons?

I am doing this in a Laravel project, I could have:

```
/* Person.php */
class Person extends Model {
}

/* Organization.php */    
class Organization extends Person {
    protected $table = 'persons';
}

/* Authority.php */    
class Authority extends Organization {
    protected $table = 'persons';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes create another table but do not repeat the data which `persons` already has, you can just use relationships for that.

For instance, create a table called `organizations` which stores persons with *organization* level. The schema can be:

```
| person_id (FK to persons.id) | manager_id | other_fields |
```

Then another table for `authorities` which stores persons with `authority` level. The schema can be:

```
| person_id (FK to persons.id) | decree_number | other_fields |
```

Then in Laravel, just create a relationship, I'm assuming a one-to-one relationship here.

```
// Person.php

public function organizationProfile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Organization::class);
}

public function authorityProfile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Authority::class);
}

public function hasOrganization()
{
    return $this->organizationProfile !== null;
}

public function hasAuthority()
{
    return $this->authorityProfile !== null;
}
```

The design is like a `Person` can have profiles (which in your case is *Organization* and *Authority*). There could be other design but this is what I've thought of.

In summary, since *Organization* and *Authority* are both **Person**s with just another attribute, we just created another table to hold those attributes but not to repeat the attributes which are already present in *Person*. We will make use of relationships to determine **if** a *Person* is just a *Person*, an *Organization* or an *Authority*.